# retain another copy of object pointers after calling destructor to reuse data

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I am working on a board based game like checkers. Every tile on the board has certain properties. Before changing the board status, I want to save it's state and use it to undo the last move. As the status changes, all objects are destructed and new ones are created. Is there any way to retain these pointers as well as calling the destructor?

Comment: If you are going to implement undo you need to store copies or abstracted information to allow the undo.... what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Caribou i am creating another class object with properties from this one and recreating using that properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to retain the pointer in this way. If you attempt to access the data through those pointers AFTER they have been deleted, you will get access violations. Once they are deleted the memory they point to should not be accessed through those pointers.

If you take copies of these pointers, they will also have the same address, so accessing that memory through the copies you take will result in the same thing happening. You need to consider a different approach

Comment: @dkumar Well yes in theory if you deep copied the object then you could access those copies safely after deleting the originals, but ask yourself why would you do this?? Your problem lies in the design. Read some of the other answers/comments for guidance.

Comment: @dkumar - "In Theory" is a figure of speech - in this case it actually  means "You could do that ". I was told by a German friend once that he ignores (pretty much) everything said by an English person up to the word "But.." because after that is the important part

Answer (score 3):

This is a design question more than a pointer/implementation question. 
One way to think of undo/redo are two stacks, one for each task

Whenever you make a move, you push the configuration/game state, objects etc.. down the undo stack as one element, when u press undo, u pop an element of that stack, apply it to your game and push this element to the redo stack.
redo stack is cleared when a new move is done

you can't use an object after calling its destructor, pointer or no pointer. you can either copy the object as a whole before pushing it down the stack, or use a pointer to it, whatever suits you

You might be interested in using shared pointers, as they offer you more possibilities

Another approach other than saving the whole game state if you want to effectively use memory, is to just save the changes in the game instead of a snapshot of the whole game, but this usually requires more work, though its the clever approach

Comment: what can be done if i want storing all steps in an array to provide many undo or redo at one click

Comment: its the same idea. you have 20 elements in your undo stack, and want to go back 10 steps, so you pop out 10 elements from the undo stack, apply them to the game, and push them into the redo stack

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can follow to retain game state:

- serialize every object that makes up the game state to memory or storage, thus effectively saving the state and being able to come back to it.
- retain only the changes from one game state to the other.

I don't think using pointers is central to your design. There's no need to retain the old pointers, and, as far as I can see, there's no need for pointers at all. You either save the old states of the objects themselves, or the series of changes. In this case, I'd go with the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a Link to UNDO list in same tile object ... as a linked list or so, and when user undo the state you manipulate the data in this list  and the data in title

Comment: @dkumar  i am not saying to put deleted pointer in the list..  put some data  from which you can go back to your previous state that is nothing but undo..